# Find the arc length of a curve. Problem integrating

Tags: calculus, algebraic-curves

The question is find the arc length of the 
parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ cut by the line $3y = 8x$ 
I applied this formula $\int(1+ (dx╱dy)^2) dy $. 
However by substituting the value of $dx/dy I$ obtain an expression $
1/2a \int(4a^2 + y^2 ) ^.5 dy$  limits $3a╱2$ to $0$.

I tried integrating this expression by substituting $y = 2a \tan(m)$ but the answer didn't match. What should I do? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried hyperbolic functions? $y=2asinht$

Answer (score 2):

I get the following:

The line cutting the parabola is $\;y=\frac83x\;$, so it cuts the parabola whenever

$$\frac{64}9x^2=y^2=4ax\iff 4x\left(\frac{16}9x-a\right)=0\iff x=0\;,\;\;x=\frac{9a}{16}$$

From this it follows at once the line intersects the parabola at the origin and at some point in the first quadrant, and here we have the function

$$y=2\sqrt a\sqrt x\implies y'=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt x}=\sqrt{\frac ax}$$

thus, the wanted length is given by

$$\int\limits_0^{\frac{9a}{16}}\sqrt{1+\frac ax}\;dx\;\ldots$$